# JavaScript, filter array of objects by a specific key's value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the best way to filter my array of objects with specific key's string. Basically what I am trying to achieve is to get the objects which contain `"Type":"Blue"`. Here is my data:

```
[
   {
       "data": [
           {}
       ],
       "Name": "1",
       "Type": "Blue"
   },
   {
       "data": [
           {}
       ],
       "Name": "2",
       "Type": "Red"
   },
   {
       "data": [
           {}
       ],
       "Name": "3",
       "Type": "Blue"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method. See the snippet below, as well as a definition of the method from MDN:

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
const data = [
  {
    data: [{}],
    Name: "1",
    Type: "Blue"
  },
  {
    data: [{}],
    Name: "2",
    Type: "Red"
  },
  {
    data: [{}],
    Name: "3",
    Type: "Blue"
  }
];

const filteredData = data.filter((item) => item.Type === "Blue");
console.log(filteredData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

```
arr.filter(obj => obj.Type == 'Blue');
```

will give you the array containing only the objects with type Blue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement correctly, You have a string `"Type: Blue"` and based on this string you have to filtered out the data array dynamically based on the `key` as Type and `value` as Blue. If Yes, Here you go **:**

```js
const str = "Type: Blue";

const splittedStr = str.split(':');

const data = [
  {
    Name: "1",
    Type: "Blue"
  },
  {
    Name: "2",
    Type: "Red"
  },
  {
    Name: "3",
    Type: "Blue"
  }
];

const filteredData = data.filter((item) => item[splittedStr[0]] === splittedStr[1].trim());

console.log(filteredData);
```